# Unable to change hosting to AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-lightsail

I have changed the hosting of my wordpress website to amazon lightsail and after that it is pointing to a deafult wordpress theme. I also get an error message that procedding to this website is not safe.

Before moving to AWS there were 2 nameservers and Amazon gives 4 nameservers i have tried 2 as well as 4 but no luck.

I have attached two images as well.

Any ideas, solutions or help would be greatly appreciated.

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHyai.jpg)

[Error Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4HVT.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you create a new Amazon Lightsail instance with WordPress, it loads a default site. This is expected behaviour. Did you try configuring the site, or migrating your wordpress site to the new instance?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am new to AWS and not sure of how to migrate wordpress to the new instance. Do you mind guiding me in the right direction?TIA!

Comment: It would be the same way you would migrate WordPress to any new computer. You should probably ask at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

You need to reinitialize the SSL certificate attached on the AWS instance.

Your certificates are'nt trusted anymore.